# Apache Storm Skipping Second CommandLine argument

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments, apache-storm

Today i came across a weird and annoying error in My Storm  Topology Builder.
The problem is When i submit my jar file to storm cluster It always skips the second argument passed to the main method.

```
public class ZMQTopology {
public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException,
                                                InvalidTopologyException {

                            for(int i=0;i<(args.length);i++)
                            {   System.out.println("I=" +i+ " value="+args[i]);
                            }
```

> This is how i submit my jar
>
> E:\target>storm jar StormZeroMQ.jar com.wipro.bdas.zeromq.ZMQTopology
>   value1 value2 value3 value4 value5

Output

> I=0 value=value1
>
> I=1 value=value3
>
> I=2 value=value4
>
> I=3 value=value5

I tried with all combination, number of arguments ,type of arguments etc. but It is skipping the second argument.
I am wondering what am i missing..
Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some amount of debugging I could find that it happens only with **windows machine** . I was able to reproduce the error in 2 windows machine. With both  0.9.3 and 0.9.4 versions of Storm .In Linux machine I could see command line parameters working perfectly.

Jira ticket raised for[ this bug.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-745
**Update : Bug Fixed for later windows Storm.cmd Version.**